# Arrange words in array in php

Tags: php, arrays, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy

Rearrange words in Array based on position of the first array. In my code there are two array my first array is the base array from which i am going to compare it with second array and make the position same as first array.

Consider 2 input 
By considering 1 input as base i am applying levenshtein(metaphone(each word database),metaphone(each word of bank)) then based on that arranging the words of bankdata in new array

databaseName = LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI
bankdata = SHASTRI LAL 
source code will only rearrange bankdata and stored in in new array 
current output of bankdata : LAL SHASTRI

Rearrangement is happening properly just need to arrange words in array

```
            $db = 'LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV';
            $bank = 'SHASTRI LAL';
            $a = reArrangeArray($db,$bank);

            function reArrangeArray($db,$bank)
            {
                $dataBaseName = $db;
                $bankdataRows = [$db,$bank,];
                $dbWords = preg_split("#[\s]+#", $dataBaseName);     
                foreach ($bankdataRows as $bankdata)
                {
                $bankWords = preg_split("#[\s]+#", trim($bankdata));
                $result    = [];    
                if(!empty($bankWords))
                    foreach ($dbWords as $dbWord)
                    {
                    $idx   = null;
                    $least = PHP_INT_MAX;
                    foreach ($bankWords as $k => $bankWord)
                        if (($lv = levenshtein(metaphone($bankWord),metaphone($dbWord))) < $least)
                        {
                        $least = $lv;
                        $idx   = $k;
                        }
                    @$result[] = $bankWords[$idx];
                    unset($bankWords[$idx]);
                    }
                $result = array_merge($result, $bankWords);
                var_dump($result);
                }
            }
```

**Case 1:**
                **CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
            array (size=4)
            0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
            1 => string 'BAHADUR' (length=7)
            2 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
            3 => string 'YADAV' (length=5)

            array (size=4)
            0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
            1 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
            2 => null
            3 => null
```

**Expected Output**

I need array position as same as databaseArray

```
            $dbName = 'LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV';
            $bankName = 'SHASTRI LAL';

            array of db (size=4)
            0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
            1 => string 'BAHADUR' (length=7)
            2 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
            3 => string 'YADAV' (length=5)

            array of bankname (size=4)
            0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
            1 => #
            2 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
            3 => ###
```

if word not found in first array it should be place with # since position is 3 which dont have matching element it has 3 #

**Case 2**

Input :

$dbName = NikithaRani MohanRao
$bankdata = Nikitha Rani Mohan Rao

Output : 
$newbankdata = NikithaRani MohanRao

It should concatenate the word if found concatenated in $dbName

Comment: What's Levenish distance? A Google search [finds no matches](https://www.google.com/search?q="leventish+distance"). Do you perhaps mean *Levenshtein* distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <?php  
            $DatabaseName = "LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV";
            $BankName = "SHASTRI LAL";

            $data = explode(" ", $DatabaseName);
            $bank = explode(" ", $BankName);
            sort($data);
            sort($bank);
            if($data == $bank){
                echo "true";
                exit;
             }

            $lev = 0;
            foreach($data as $key => $name){
                $lev += levenshtein($name, $bank[$key]);
            } 
            echo PHP_EOL . $lev; 
            ?>
```